# Split a string in java?

Tags: java

I have this `String` :

```
10841-F-13930426-omme-salame--hamsare-geramiye-rasoule-khoda_split_005.png
```

How i can just get `Last int`.

I need to get `005.png` and then get 5 (In java).

Notice : The length of `Strings` is different .

Comment: Will there always be a `_` in front of the last number?

Comment: Yes . Just different length string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you should do the following:

```
String str = "10841-F-13930426-omme-salame--hamsare-geramiye-rasoule-khoda_split_005.png";
String last = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("_") + 1);
String[] lastParts = last.split("\\.");
int integetPart = Integer.valueOf(lastParts[0]);
```

It may not be the most fancy way, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the substring method in Java which will get part of a string past a given integer.

Say we had:

```
String str = "HelloWorld";
```

and we wanted to only show the 'World' part then we could use:

```
str.substring(5);
```

And because in your string you want the characters after the last "_" we can use the 'lastIndexOf' method in Java:

```
str.lastIndexOf("_");
```

The 'lastIndexOf' method in Java will find the amount of characters till the last _ in the string. Then because we don't want to include the _ in the outputed string we just + 1

Heres an example of how to do it once you combine the two 'substring' and 'lastIndexOf' methods together:

```
String str = "10841-F-13930426-omme-salame--hamsare-geramiye-rasoule-khoda_split_005.png";
System.out.println(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("_") + 1));
```

Outputs:

```
005.png
```

Let me know if your still having trouble :)

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "qwerty1qwerty2";      
str = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " ");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(str.trim().split(" ")));
```

Output:

```
[1, 2]
```

[EDIT]

If you want to include - a.e minus, add -?:

```
String str = "qwerty-1qwerty-2 455 f0gfg 4";      
str = str.replaceAll("[^-?0-9]+", " "); 
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(str.trim().split(" ")));
```

Output:

```
[-1, -2, 455, 0, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below. This will give you `5` as the output

```
String s = "10841-F-13930426-omme-salame--hamsare-geramiye-rasoule-khoda_split_005.png";
System.out.println(Long.valueOf(s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("_")+1).split("\\.")[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the "." character index of the string.
2. iterate backwards from the "." character until you hit a NON-number.
3. Sub string that part from start of numeric character to end (where you found you "." char).

Comment: The other answers are valid, but assumes that the file string always ends with a "_" character before the numbers .. If that is the case these suggestions work .. a more dynamic way is to move back from the "." character and find the last nummeric character .. and from that point substr what is in between those two indexes ..